# Need a simple benchmarker for rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, benchmarking

The idea is to implement benchmark tests, like it is done in `rails-perftest`. But I found some problems using it in rails 4.

Could you suggest simple benchmarker gem for rails 4?

Answer (score 0):

there are some gems you can use in your project.

```
gem 'method_profiler'
gem 'rbench'
gem 'bench_press'
gem 'better-benchmark'
gem 'Tach'
```